# How do I get back lost data from Virtual Box VM?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I’ve been using Linux Mint for close to a year on a Win 10 host using Virtual Box (current ver 6.1). About a week ago, my Win 10 machine auto-rebooted (curse them) and when I powered my Linux Mint VM back on it appears I’ve been restored to the Snapshot taken months ago. I don’t have any files or applications on the VM that were installed/created since.

I’m pretty sure (but not certain) that when Win 10 rebooted that I had already closed the VM using “save state”. So, when I look at the Snapshots directory for my VM I see a saved state from 11/1, that I think would contain everything I need, but when I start the VM it is restoring me to a point from June. The VDI files are after I tried opening the VM and found everything was missing.

[Screen cap of file folder showing SAV & VDI files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICfju.png)

Any suggestions as to how to recover my lost data?

FURTHER INFO:
List of Snapshots:

- Only 1 as of 11/10 when I discovered my lost data, and it is dated from June. The only other Snapshot info is from when I cloned the VM after, thinking I would use the clone to experiment with ways to restore the data.
  [VM Snapshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2Fix.jpg)

Logs:

- Not sure which log you need, I have multiple [logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRaEJ.jpg), I'll attach the first.
  https://drive.google.com/file/d/12uHecsu80Xf5DT07150HLzsic-BlwPr_/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The .sav file dated 11/1, you are pointing at, actually doesn't contain your lost files.Please note that they are different from .vdi files.

From [**vmware - support**](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/new_guest_what_ws.html)

> **.vmx.sav or .cfg.sav - the configuration snapshot**
> **file, which stores the configuration of a virtual machine at the time**
> **you take a snapshot of it.**

From [.SAV file created by snapshot](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=52045)

> **The .sav file is essentially a memory dump, though other processor
> information (such as registers) is probably stored too.** Precise format
> information can no doubt be found in the source code.
>
> **.sav files are stored in the "Snapshots" subfolder, but they really
> have nothing to do with snapshots.**

From [quora - What-is-a-sav-file-in-VirtualBox](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-sav-file-in-VirtualBox)

> They are configuration files saved, everytime you changed the settings
> of the VM. Say you started with a 1 virtual cpu and 2 GB RAM config
> initially and decided 1 CPU is too low and added another CPU to your
> VM. You have created a .sav file. Every change you mad. creates such a
> file. These files allow you to go back to an earlier stage of this VM.
> If you are sure that you will not need the config files from 2 years
> ago, you can delete them.

From [about-sav-file-created-by-snapshots](https://vbox-dev.virtualbox.narkive.com/ScUlvhwy/about-sav-file-created-by-snapshots)

> a .sav file contains always the complete state of the guest at a
> certain point in time. **It does not contain any information stored on
> external devices like virtual disks**. When a snapshot is created, a
> .sav file is created containing the VM state which is required to
> restore the guest state for that time and a new differential disk
> image is created for each virtual disk (which is not attached in some
> special mode to prevent that). From now on, guest disk write requests
> go to the differential image. When you restore a snapshat, the
> differential image is removed so all changes to the disk after the
> snapshot was created are lost.
>
> A .sav file is created using the SSM (saved state manager) code. You
> will find the API in include/VBox/vmm/ssm.h and
> src/VBox/VMM/VMMR3/SSM.cpp.

Comment: Thanks for the info, so it doesn't sound like I will be able to recover my lost files through the SAV files. Do you know of any way to check through the VDI files to see if the data is in there? Or any other suggestions?

I appreciate your time.

Comment: @CliftonHill have you tried restorings the most recent Snapshot?also attach an image of virtualbox showing list of available Snapshots

Comment: I haven't. The Snapshot shows it is from June. Side question: Is there some chance whatever happened is stored in the logs? I don't know how to read them.

Comment: @CliftonHill Every time Oracle VM VirtualBox starts up a VM, a so-called release log file is created, containing lots of information about the VM configuration and runtime events. The log file is called VBox.log and resides in the VM log file folder, which is $HOME/VirtualBox VMs/VM-name/Logs by default.

When starting a VM, the configuration file of the last run will be renamed to .1, up to .3. ctd ...

Comment: Also VirtualBox Manager window can show these logs in a window. To access it, select a virtual machine from the list on the left and select Show Log from the Machine menu. Share the logs ,let's see if i can help. Also as requested in my previous comment , edit your question and attach image of virtualbox showing list of available Snapshots

Comment: The screenshot you attached in the question shows the latest vdi created was on 10/11 i.e on Tuesday. And you said latest snapshots are from June. Can you clarify/identify which info is wrong?

Comment: Thanks for still looking this over, I edited my question to include a pic of the Snapshots screen, a pic of the various logs and a link to the log I think you need.